# Small sample program gives me an error

Tags: c++

My sample program is so small that i am going to give you all the source code below:

So here is ClassA header:

```
#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H
#include <string>

class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA(const std::string& fileName,  int TYPE = 0, float filter = 0.0f);
    ClassA(int width = 0, int height = 0, unsigned char* data = 0, int TYPE = 0, float   filter = 0.0f);
    ClassA(ClassA& classa);
    void operator=(ClassA& classa);
protected:

private:
    std::string m_lastBind;
    int m_textureTarget;
    bool m_freeTexture;
    int m_width;
    int m_height;
    float m_float;

};

#endif // CLASSA_H
```

Here is the source file for the ClassA:

```
#include "classa.h"

ClassA::ClassA(const std::string& fileName, int TYPE, float filter)
{
    m_lastBind = fileName;
    m_textureTarget = TYPE;
    m_float = filter;
}


static unsigned char whitePixel[] = {'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'};

ClassA::ClassA(int width, int height, unsigned char* data, int TYPE, float filter)
{
    m_width = width;
    m_height = height;
    data = whitePixel;
    m_textureTarget = TYPE;
    m_float = filter;
}


ClassA::ClassA(ClassA& classa)
{
    m_width = classa.m_width;
    m_height = classa.m_height;
    m_textureTarget = classa.m_textureTarget;
    m_float = classa.m_float;
}
```

Here is the header file for ClassB:

```
#ifndef CLASSB_H
#define CLASSB_H
#include <string>

class ClassB
{
    public:
        void someMethod(const int& num1, const int& num2, std::string& name);
    protected:

    private:
};

#endif // CLASSB_H
```

And finally the definition of the one and only method of ClassB is given below:

```
#include "classb.h"
#include "classa.h"

static unsigned char whitePixel[] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};
void ClassB::someMethod(const int& num1, const int& num2, std::string& name)
{
    static ClassA WHITE = ClassA(1,1,whitePixel);
}
```

The main function is pretty much irrelevant because it is completely empty and has nothing to do with the errors i am getting from Code::Blocks. The errors are given below:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Testing2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
classb.cpp||In member function ‘void ClassB::someMethod(const int&, const int&, std::string&)’:|
classb.cpp|8|error: no matching function for call to ‘ClassA::ClassA(ClassA)’|
classb.cpp|8|note: candidates are:|
classa.h|10|note: ClassA::ClassA(ClassA&)|
classa.h|10|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ClassA’ to ‘ClassA&’|
classa.h|9|note: ClassA::ClassA(int, int, unsigned char*, int, float)|
classa.h|9|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ClassA’ to ‘int’|
classa.h|8|note: ClassA::ClassA(const string&, int, float)|
classa.h|8|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ClassA’ to ‘const string& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}’|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Your compiler don't know the type of parameters (ex. int or reference). You should cast 1st parameter (maybe 2nd parameter too) to int.

Comment: @VuDang: no! The compiler knows the types.

Comment: @Mat Looks to me like it can take `int`, `int`, `unsigned char*` (since the remaining parameters are optional), and that appears to be what's being passed in....care to give us another hint?

Comment: @KyleStrand: you're right, misread the error message...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
static ClassA WHITE = ClassA(1,1,whitePixel);
```

needs a copy-constructor in order to work. The constructor `ClassA(ClassA&)` won't match because temporaries cannot bind to lvalue-references. You can make the constructor take a reference to `const` instead.

```
ClassA(ClassA const&);
```

This works because temporaries (rvalues) can bind to lvalue-references to `const`.

---

What were you were doing was creating a temporary `ClassA` value and *copy-constructing* `WHITE` from that. This is called *copy-initialization*. If you use *direct-initialization* instead:

```
static ClassA WHITE(1,1,whitePixel);
```

---

A copy-constructor simply copies all the members of the parameter to the object being created. Your code effectively does exactly the same thing. Fortunately the compiler will provide a copy-constructor for you by default, so **you don't need to make one yourself**.

Comment: Why is the compiler interpreting a constructor call with three arguments as a call to the copy constructor?

Comment: @KyleStrand During overload resolution the compiler assembles candidates for the call. When it fails it lists the candidates and why they were not viable. My answer goes over what I think he believed was the copy-constructor.

Comment: That Worked even though i am not in a position to fully understand that.

Comment: Right, and the reason the copy constructor is not viable appears to be because the first argument, `1`, is for some reason considered an instance of `classA` (unless I'm misreading the error message). Why is that?

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if it provided the improved code: `static ClassA WHITE(1, 1, whitePixel)`. There is _no_ reason to make the class copyable just for the OP's declaration.

Comment: @Kyle: No. You take a temporary `ClassA` (on the RHS of the `=`) and attempt to construct `WHITE` from it. That requires copy construction. Instead simply directly declare `WHITE` as I did in my previous comment and in my answer.

Comment: @0x499602D2 _"Also, nice avatar."_ You should get some cooler hats, fitting for it ;-). Merry XMas!

Answer (score 3):

```
static ClassA WHITE = ClassA(1,1,whitePixel);
```

This constructs a temporary `ClassA`, then copy-constructs `WHITE` from it. The copy might be removed by optimisation but it *must* be possible.

You should simply directly declare `WHITE`:

```
static ClassA WHITE(1, 1, whitePixel);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static ClassA WHITE = ClassA(1,1,whitePixel);
```

This is a copy-initialization, which semantically first creates the right part and then initializes the left part by calling copy constructor (this call may be elided but copy constructor still must be available). For direct initialization rewrite it as

```
static ClassA WHITE(1,1,whitePixel);
```

That said, copy constructor still should take a const reference or even be removed, as suggested by 0x499602D2.